# Orange Error During Installing Text Add On

Tags: text-mining, orange, anaconda

I am trying to install the Text add-on (version 0.7.3) for Orange (version 3.23) on my Win10, but I am getting the following error during the building "ufal_udpipe":

```
Command failed: python python -m pip install --constraint 'C:\Users\Jakub\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb4fneogu.txt' Orange3-Text exited with non zero status.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Jakub\AppData\Local\Orange\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Jakub\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r71cit89\\ufal.udpipe\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Jakub\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r71cit89\\ufal.udpipe\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Jakub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gtt8e801\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I also tried to install Microsoft Visual C++, because it´s required in the log, but the problem is the same after the installation.

I tried to install add-on throught the Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install orange3-text
```

This process failed, because:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::commonmark-0.9.0-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\Jakub\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done
```

The result of *conda clean* command is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 112, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .common.io import timeout
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .._vendor.tqdm import tqdm
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._tqdm import tqdm
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\_tqdm.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._utils import _supports_unicode, _environ_cols_wrapper, _range, _unich, \
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\_utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    colorama.init()
AttributeError: module 'colorama' has no attribute 'init'
```

Reinstall of Orange and Anaconda didn´t help.

Full extract of logs is here: [Google Disk](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Zf0wM02XiC8Sucnn6nSqkqbyaM1-MUVa?usp=sharing)

Thank you for your help! 
Jakub

Answer (score 0):

I encountered just the first line of your error. I checked if I had python and anaconda installed properly or not (and I had). I then kept trying to install and in the 4th go it installed without an issue- now my guess is maybe network issues caused the error to occur.

Another thing suggested to me by their support was- "Yes, we are aware of the issue. Somewhere in the process we accidentally disabled the necessary setting. Go to Options - Settings, find the Add-ons tab and select 'Install add-ons with conda'. This should install Text successfully."

Comment: I tried to install add-on with checked Install add-ons with conda in Settings, but it doesn´t work.

I also tried to install another add-on (Geo, version 0.2.4), and the result is the same.

Comment: I suggest contact their support- they are very responsive

Comment: Yes, I did it. Their support (my issue is here: https://github.com/biolab/orange3-text/issues/437) recomended to install add-on via Orange Command Prompt. Do you know, how to do it? I don´t have any experinece with virtual environment. Thank you! :)

Comment: Try Options->Settings->Add-ons and put the commands in the box provided under "Pip install arguments"

Comment: Thank you! I put the command like "pip install orange3-text" into Pip install arguments and tried to install add-on. The result is below. I am not sure, if my process is correct.                          RESULT: Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\jakub\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (19.2.2)
Collecting install
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for install

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found the issue fix (at least for me - comment if it works for you).

How to fix it:

Download Colorama
Copy the "Colorama" from the download then replace the folder named "colorama" in C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

I suspect this issue occurs because of ([issue 8842](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8842))